# automate group_by function with different group rules r

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

| grade | year | campus | TestType | OriginalScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fresh | 2021 | FL | reading | 80 |
| fresh | 2021 | NY | reding | 85 |
| senior | 1999 | FL | writing | 100 |
| senior | 1999 | FL | writing | 95 |
| fresh | 1999 | FL | reading | 100 |

I have different dataframes storing test scores and other information like above. Above is a toy table for English, as a test category. What I need to do is to calculate mean and sd by grouping the scores by grade, year, campus etc, like so:

```
aggEnglishTable <- dfEng %>%
group_by (grade, TestType) %>%
summarize_at(vars(OriginalScore) funs(mean, sd))
```

However, depending on the subject, say (math, SAT, foreign language etc.), I need different grouping rules. I created a meta table to note different grouping rules like so:

| TestCategory | grade | year | campus | TestType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| English | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Math | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| SAT | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I'm wondering how to automate this process by mapping the information from the meta grouping rule table to the group_by commands. The column names I can extract from the meta group rules table are strings, but how to make it into something the group_by commands can receive?

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: please include a proper repruducible example with the original larger dataframe that contains all TestCategories.

Comment: Your data should be provided as code, NOT AS A FORMATTED TABLE.
Please use `dput(data)`

Comment: What is `TestCategory`?

Comment: It's like subject. Like for English as a category, it has test type including reading and writing. Different categories have their own grouping rules.

Comment: So it's not related to `TestType`?

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer would be to create a function with the dataframe and grouping variables as parameters. Using `group_by_at` allows you to pass strings to group the dataframe.

```
dfEng <- 
    data.frame(grade = c('fresh', 'fresh', 'senior', 'senior', 'fresh'),
    year = c(2021, 2021, 1999, 1999, 1999), 
    campus = c('FL', 'NY', rep('FL',3)), 
    OriginalScore = c(80, 85, 100, 95, 100))

fn_summarize <- function(df_in, grouping_vars){
    
    df_in %>%
        group_by_at(vars(all_of(grouping_vars))) %>%
        summarize_at(vars(OriginalScore), list(mean = mean, sd = sd)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        return()

}

aggEnglishTable <- fn_summarize(dfEng, c('grade', 'year'))
```

Then for the rest of the subjects, you would just follow the last line:

```
aggMathTable <- fn_summarize(dfMath, c('grade', 'year', 'campus'))
```

Please remember to put sample data in your question in future.